# Unit test case MockRestServiceServer expected url is not working with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing

I have test a url class which validate url

```
class ValidateUrl {
    public Integer validateUrl(String url, int timeOut) throws Exception {
        String url;
        private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(1000 * timeOut);
            ResultClass result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, ResultClass.class);
            if(result!= null) {
                return result.getErrorCode();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error"+ e);
        }
        return -1;

    }
}
```

i have create a test case of test class 
 ValidateUrlTest where i am validating the url

```
@Autowire
private ValidateUrl validateUrlInstance

private String url = "https://testingurl.com";
private String result = "{\"result\" : \"-1\"}";

@Test
public void validateUrlTest() throws Exception{
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(factory);
    MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(template);
    server.expect(requestTo(url))
            .andRespond(given());
    int i= validateUrlInstance.validateUrl(url, 2);
    server.verify();

}
```

but getting 
 java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected
   [testng] 0 out of 1 were executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of `RestTemplate` you are mocking is not the one used in `ValidateUrl` class.

You should inject it instead of intanciating it straight in the method.

```
public class ValidateUrl {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ValidateUrl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public Integer validateUrl(String url, int timeOut) throws Exception {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/ please look the example these is also not instantiated RestTemplate , i have seen many MockRestServiceServer example where they are just autowire the RestTemplate only ;(

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying in the example you send me the RestTemplate is injected (with Spring's @Autowired), but in your code, RestTemplate is instanciated inside your service method and not injected.